# Check multiple columns with value NULL in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, case-when

Currently I have the following sql statement:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN sd.GV01 IS NULL 
         AND sd.GV02 IS NULL 
         AND sd.GV03 IS NULL 
         AND sd.GV04 IS NULL 
         AND sd.GV05 IS NULL
         AND sd.CountryId = '4' THEN 4
    END AS rating
FROM masterData sd
```

I tried to take the same way with a more short definition:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN NULL IN (sd.GV01, sd.GV02, sd.GV03, sd.GV04, sd.GV05)
         AND sd.CountryId = '4' THEN 4
    END AS rating
FROM masterData sd
```

But I don't get return values, why? Can someone give me a better solution?

Comment: when coalesce(sd.GV01, ... sd.GV05) is null

Comment: `NULL` cannot be compared to like other values. `NULL = NULL` does not return `true`, and neither does `NULL IN (0,1,NULL)`; they both return `NULL`. *On a side note `NULL` acts "oddly" (but documented) when using `NOT IN` and it's actually recommended to `NOT EXISTS`. Notice what happens with this query: `SELECT 1 WHERE 1 NOT IN (0,1,NULL);`*

Comment: Even if it was valid SQL, that's not the same statement anyway.  In the first you're using AND.  In the second you're using IN which is like using lots of ORs.

Comment: @Zorkolot Oh yeah right. Thank you.. I forgot it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is fine.  Almost any comparison of `NULL` values returns `NULL` -- which is treated as false.

You could use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COALESCE(sd.GV01, sd.GV02, sd.GV03, sd.GV04, sd.GV05) IS NULL AND
                  sd.CountryId = '4'
             THEN 4
        END) AS rating
FROM masterData sd;
```